# Azure Data Factory - Copy data is converting excel file to application/octet-stream

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline in data factory that is moving an excel file from a folder named inbound to a folder named raw, but it copies the excel file as "application/octet-stream". How do I get it so it keeps the file as "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"? Here is the code I have for the copy.

```
{
                            "name": "Copy from Inbound",
                            "type": "Copy",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "source": {
                                    "type": "DelimitedTextSource",
                                    "storeSettings": {
                                        "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                                        "recursive": true,
                                        "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                                    },
                                    "formatSettings": {
                                        "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                                    }
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "type": "DelimitedTextSink",
                                    "storeSettings": {
                                        "type": "AzureBlobFSWriteSettings"
                                    },
                                    "formatSettings": {
                                        "type": "DelimitedTextWriteSettings",
                                        "quoteAllText": true,
                                        "fileExtension": ".txt"
                                    }
                                },
                                "enableStaging": false,
                                "translator": {
                                    "type": "TabularTranslator",
                                    "typeConversion": true,
                                    "typeConversionSettings": {
                                        "allowDataTruncation": true,
                                        "treatBooleanAsNumber": false
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "inputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "Blob",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "container": "inbound",
                                        "folder": {
                                            "value": "@replace(pipeline().parameters.filePath, 'inbound/', '')",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        },
                                        "file": {
                                            "value": "@pipeline().parameters.fileName",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            "outputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "Blob",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "container": "raw",
                                        "folder": {
                                            "value": "@concat(replace(pipeline().parameters.filePath, 'inbound/', ''),'/',formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyy-mm-dd'))",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        },
                                        "file": {
                                            "value": "@pipeline().parameters.fileName",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no setting available to add a content-type property of a file in Copy data activity when loaded to storage. The default content type added to the file loaded to blob is application/octet-stream.

You can raise a feature request from the Azure data factory.

[image]

As a temporary solution, you follow the suggestion given by MartinJaffer-MSFT in the [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/470237/how-to-set-content-type-when-copy-to-blob-storage.html) forum.

Use Web activity after your copy data activity to make a request to [set the blob properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/set-blob-properties).